# Can Mid 2012 Macbook pro be upgraded using nvme ssd using an adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade

I'm looking to upgrade the storage on a 2012 macbook pro, and moving to an ssd. I know that I could just get a 2.5 inch drive in the optical drive bay, but I would rather keep the optical drive.

Is there a way to use a nvme ssd in a mid 2012 macbook pro model? I know an adapter is needed, so what adapter works? Also, I've heard that certain brands of nvme ssds work, so some confirmation on that would be helpful.

I dont know if OS version matters, but it is is el captian version :10.11.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [M.2 PCIe to SATA adaptors](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2-in1-M-2-NVMe-SATA-Bus-NGFF-SSD-to-PCI-e-U-2-SFF-8639-Adapter-PCIe-M2-Converter/264319550695) that you could use, but there are two problems: Firstly, you're not going to see the faster speed of the NVM RAM, because the SATA interface is the bottleneck, and won't go any faster than 6 Gbps.
Secondly, ensuring that the adaptor card and the new SSD module will all fit together inside your laptop: neither being too big, nor rattling around loose.

The simplest thing is to replace the existing mechanical hard drive with a [2.5" SATA SSD](https://uk.crucial.com/gbr/en/ct1000mx500ssd1). This will slot in exactly in place of your old drive, and will cost less than an NVM RAM module.

(Links to UK stores.)

Answer (score -1):

Apart from benwiggy's answer, which is the rational choice, it is also possible to solder to de-solder the ThunderBolt chip and re-use its PCIe lanes using an adapter.
A company called iBolt provides a kit to do that, it requires modifying the motherboard had to be done by you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvrygDOf0s8